# Custom Join Conditions. Left Join on ID and Nearest less than date. SQL or Python Solution

Tags: python, mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying to join 2 tables.
Table 1 contains Id, a date column and a value column.
Table 2 also has Id, a date column and different value columns.

I need to join Table 1 (as left) with Table 2 (to the right) by the same record Id and by the nearest less than date in Table 1 for the dates in Table 2. So the join would first match the ID then it would look for the nearest less than date in Table 1 for the dates in Table 2. So if there is no dates in Table 1 which is less than Table 2 for the corresponding ID, then no value for Table 2 will be added, for that ID.

I want to show all the records from Table 1, and only the value columns from Table 2. So if I have 100,000 rows in Table 1 then I want my final Joined Table to also have 100,000 rows.

Here is a simplified version and example of what I am hoping to achieve. In the simplified example there is only 1 value column in Table 2 but I have 15.

Here's the SQL code to create the dummy table:

```
drop table if exists table1;
drop table if exists table2;

create table table1 (id text, date date, val int);
create table table2 (id text, date date, val int);

insert into table1 (id, date, val)
values ('sn1', '2010/01/26', 10),
       ('sn1', '2010/01/25', 9),
       ('sn1', '2010/01/21', 8),
       ('sn2', '2010/01/23', 9),
       ('sn2', '2010/01/22', 7),
       ('sn1', '2010/01/19', 10);
insert into table1 (id, date, val) values ('sn2', '2010/01/18', 11);
select * from table1 order by 1,2;

insert into table2 (id, date, val) values ('sn1', '2010/01/26', 20);
insert into table2 (id, date, val) values ('sn2', '2010/01/23', 99);
insert into table2 (id, date, val) values ('sn2', '2010/01/17', 50);
insert into table2 (id, date, val) values ('sn2', '2010/01/21', 60);
insert into table2 (id, date, val) values ('sn1', '2010/01/20', 0);
select * from table2 order by 1,2;
```

Below shows the desired result. It has all the columns and rows from Table 1 and the last column from 2.

```
+------+------------+------+------+
| id   | date       | val1 | val2 |
+------+------------+------+------+
| sn1  | 2010-01-19 |   10 |    0 |
| sn1  | 2010-01-21 |    8 |      |
| sn1  | 2010-01-25 |    9 |      |
| sn1  | 2010-01-26 |   10 |   20 |
| sn2  | 2010-01-18 |   11 |   60 |
| sn2  | 2010-01-22 |    7 |      |
| sn2  | 2010-01-23 |    9 |   99 |
+------+------------+------+------+
```

Any help would be appreciated, be it may in SQL (preferable) or Python.

Thank You

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Go on. Try something. (Also, just to note, we tend to reserve the term 'id' specifically for an autoincrementing, surrogate PK.) Also, always explicitly identify the PK in each case. And incidentally, I think this problem is rather tricky

Comment: @Pasha . . . Your explanation just doesn't make sense.  The earliest value for sn1 in table2 is on 2010-01-20, but you are giving that value to 2010-01-19.  Further, you seem to have a requirement for only assigning a table2 value once, but you don't explain what to do when there are multiple possibilities.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry 
The id here is just for illustration purposes for the join. The actual unique PK are different for each of the tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I only need to update Table 1 with some additional info that is/if available in Table 2, hence the corresponding value from Table 2 is assigned to Table 1. As for the earliest value for sn1 in Table 2, as mentioned it is either joined with a matching date in Table 1, if not then the nearest less than date, which is why, it goes with 19th as there are no data in table 1 for the corresponding id for 20th. You can also see the value for 2010/01/17 in Table 2 is dropped as there are no corresponding or less than date available in Table 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.`date`, t1.val val1, t2.val val2
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.`date` >= t1.`date` 
                   AND t2.id = t1.id
                   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                                   FROM table1 t3
                                   WHERE t3.`date` > t1.`date`
                                     AND t2.`date` >= t3.`date`
                                     AND t3.id = t1.id)
ORDER BY id, `date`;
```

or

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS (SELECT id, `date`, val val1, NULL val2
         FROM table1
        UNION ALL
         SELECT id, `date`, NULL val1, val val2
         FROM table2),
cte2 AS (SELECT id, 
                `date`, 
                val1, 
                CASE WHEN val2 IS NULL
                     THEN LEAD(val2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `date`, val2)
                     ELSE val2
                     END val2
         FROM cte1)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE val1 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id, `date`;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7be68bd218de603eb50b9cfac33562c7)